# How to accept objects of multiple types in C# function?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, declaration

Right now I have two functions:

```
public void func(Unity.Collections.NativeArray<ushort> a){}

public void func(Unity.Collections.NativeArray<short> a){}
```

The functions are the exact same besides the object datatype input.  I am also not writing to these NativeArrays, so the code functions identically whether it is reading the array as <ushort> or <short>. Is there a way to combine these into one function that can accept both types of objects?  NativeArrays are a managed type, so I can't use pointers.  Any other ways to avoid duplicating the whole function or duplicating the objects?

Comment: Depending on what each `func` instance does you could use code reuse at the private level by sharing logic via methods or types. At the public level you could leave the signatures as you have them.

Comment: Unsigned short range is different from signed short. Would it be a problem for the function behaviour ?

Comment: The function is a custom implementation of a blur function.  So all it does is smooth the values.  It doesn't care where zero is; as long as the numbers are all 2 bytes.

Comment: Is a func returning void a function?

Comment: It actually has more NativeArrays being passed into the function as well.  It changes those NativeArrays instead of returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The function is a custom implementation of a blur function. So all it does is smooth the values. It doesn't care where zero is; as long as the numbers are all 2 bytes.

In that case, then, I wonder if what you *really* want is: spans.

Consider:

```cs
public void func(Unity.Collections.NativeArray<ushort> a)
  => func(MemoryMarshal.Cast<ushort, short>(a.AsSpan()));

public void func(Unity.Collections.NativeArray<short> a)
  => func(a.AsSpan());

private void func(Span<short> a)
{ ... real code here ...}
```

which uses `Span<short>` for the real code, and reinterprets the `ushort` version to use the `short` code - allowing you to work with the values without copying / casting the values individually

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'NativeArray<ushort>' does not contain a definition for 'AsSpan'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @sdugan I got that from the unity refs, so: maybe it needs a newer version; what version are you using?

Comment: I was using 2021.3.1f1.  Seeing this comment, I tried upgrading to 2022.1.22f1.  Still no luck.

Comment: @sdugan maybe it is a work in progress? https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/NativeArray/NativeArray.cs#L832

Comment: Got it, it is only in the 2023 alpha so far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public void func<T>(Unity.Collections.NativeArray<T> a) where T : struct
{}
```

<strike>perhaps adding any constraints that `NativeArray<T>` requires, such as `where T : struct` or `where T : unmanaged`</strike> (I found and edited for this; the `T : struct` is the relevant one)

Note that until C# 11 / .NET 7, operators (math etc) and generics are a pain to work with together, so if you're summing/averaging etc based on the values: that might be hard.